# Creating a loop code for word length

Tags: python

My goal is to have this code return the length of what word is inserted.

```
def word_length( word ):
word = 0
for x in word:
    int(x) += 1
return result
```

> File "[user code]", line 4    SyntaxError: can't assign to function
>   call

Comment: What do you intend for `int(x) += 1` to do?  Come to think of it, what do you expect this code to do *at all* and *why*?

Comment: Not sure what `int(x) += 1` is meant to do. Also, your function takes in an argument then instantly overwrites it. Is that what you wanted? Lastly, there is already a built-in function to get the length of a string. Why aren't you using that?

Comment: Where word in line 2, x in line 3, and int(x) in line 4 I was given blanks. I'm supposed to create a loop function and honestly I'm just really confused. If I could get any feedback to how I'm supposed to fill those blanks in and why I would really appreciate it.

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense. I think you need to have a talk with your teacher because you appear to have some fundamental misunderstanding about how a Python program is supposed to work. BTW, you can get the length of a string named `word` by doing `len(word)`, but I guess the point of this assignment is to write your own word_length function.

Comment: @PaulCapreo: I guess to give you a hint for your homework... You want to (1) create a new integer variable set to 0, (2) loop over the characters in `word`, (3) increment that integer variable in the loop.  Start with the first step... Do you know how to declare a variable in Python?  If not, you should *definitely* refer to your introductory course materials.

Comment: finally figured it out, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with int(x)

I think this is what you're attempting to do:

```
def word_length(word):
    count = 0
    for x in word:
        count += 1
    return count

word_length('Hello')
Out[8]: 5
```

Edit: Although, you could just do this without writing your own function

```
In[1]: len('Hello')
Out[1]: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_length( word ):
  i = 0
  for x in word:
      i += 1
  return i
```